# How to reference a styled component that is in a different dom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I like to add styling to a styled component that is in a different dom.

[image]

Like this Material-ui Menu component example, the dashboard button is highlighted gray, and the menu drop is highlighted light blue.

They are written in the same component file but they are in different dom.

I like to add styling to the `Menu` component from `Button` component.

Is that possible?

Demo sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/si8tr5?file=/demo.js

Menu material ui official doc: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#basic-menu

index.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import {DisplayMenu, DisplayButton} from './styles'

export default function BasicMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DisplayButton
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Dashboard
      </DisplayButton>
      <DisplayMenu
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </DisplayMenu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';

export const DisplayMenu = styled(Menu)`
  padding: 20px;
`;

DisplayMenu.displayName = 'DisplayMenu';

export const DisplayButton = styled(Button)`
  margin: 10px;

  ${DisplayMenu}{
    & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 300px;
  }
  }
`;

DisplayButton.displayName = 'DisplayButton';
```

I know just doing this below will work but this is just an example and the reality is more complicated.

I just made it simple to ask this question here.

```
export const DisplayMenu = styled(Menu)`
  padding: 20px;
  & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 300px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code won't work because you are applying styles to descendent `DisplayMenu` components (`DisplayButton` is a sibling). I don't really think it makes sense to do this but you could select the sibling:

```
export const DisplayButton = styled(Button)`
  margin: 10px;

  & + ${DisplayMenu}{
    & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 300px;
  }
  }
`;
```

I think styling `DisplayMenu` directly makes the most sense (your last approach).

However If this is a permutation of `DisplayMenu` when used with a button, I think you should consider making the wrapper div into a styled component since that allows you to apply contextual styles to the menu (change its style based on 'where' it was used):

```
const MenuButton = styled.div`
  ${DisplayMenu}{
    & .MuiPaper-root {
      width: 300px;
  }
`
// And use this in your component
<MenuButton>
 <DisplayButton {...} />
 <DisplayMenu {...} />
</MenuButton>
```

This way we only add the `width` to `DisplayMenu` when used within the context of `MenuButton`